# What's the best wording for a notification with multiple actions?

Tags: notification, wording

I'm developing an application where users can add charts and graphs to a workspace. Every time they add a chart to their workspace, I want to provide them with a banner notification that says something along the lines of this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXRglz.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

My problem lies in the wording of the notification. In the example above, **new** and **existing** would be links to the same area of the application, but different experiences. (Creating a new project and adding to an existing project).

I want the users to know they can add it to a new OR existing project, but I don't want to give them multiple links in one notification. What's the best way to word the notification so the user knows they can do both? Is it acceptable to have multiple links in a notification?

Comment: If both links take the user to the same location, why not highlight them together? "Add this chart to a new or existing project" isn't confusing to me.

Comment: @AlanGeorge It takes them to the same location, but it would be different experiences. So adding to an existing project has different steps than adding to a new project.

Comment: Unless you are using anchor tags to jump them to a specific part of the page, or different calls to a controller, I would argue the links should not be separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Success! You have added a chart. [Add it to your project](http://www.google.com).

Comment: Why are you linking to Google?

Comment: Although this answer needs a bit more explanation to meet UX.SE standards, I think the message itself might work well here. "Your project" could apply to a new or existing one.

Comment: @DavidPostill I think it was attempting to emulate a link for the answer (or maybe Google needs a chart).

Comment: yes, my answers was too ambiguous. The link was indeed to emulate that the whole message after confirmation verbiage was to be a link thus increasing awareness and hitzone.

It also makes the assumption that the front ends has the logic to take the user to the correct experience

Answer (score -1):

Just show it that item is added to the cart. You don't have to mention in which section of cart it's been added in notification area. Keep it as minimal as possible. Because notification are supposed to inform not to explain action in detail.

Comment: Could you edit this post. Your point isn't clearly understood.